# Merge all files from the current folder and all subfolders in one file using .bat file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, merge, directory

I'm looking for a batch file that merges the content of all files in the current directory and files from all subdirectories.
Also, that would be perfect if files were separated by several new lines in the big file and probably contain the filename with filepath above the each file content.

For example, there are two files in the current folder  **D:**\ , where our batch file is located:

1.
**d:\file1.txt** contains:

```
some
text here
hahaha
```

2.
**d:\folderabc\file2.mp3** contains:

```
doremi text
```

I run merge.bat file on `d:\` and it creates a merge file result.txt (or whatever extension) with such content:

```
=========d:\file1.txt=========
some
text here
hahaha



=========d:\folderabc\file2.mp3=========
doremi
```

I appreciate if someone share his solution for this problem.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this with your folder.  It assumes the files are text files.

**edit:** This has a fix - and you can remove the `"d:\base\folder"` to run it from the current directory.

```
@echo off
for /r "d:\base\folder" %%a in (*) do (
   (
    echo =========%%a=========
    type "%%a"
    echo(
    echo(
    echo(
   )>>"%temp%\temp.file"
)
move "%temp%\temp.file" . >nul
echo done
pause
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's over 80% what I expected. Looks interesting, but it works even for .php files, however not for .html files. Right, I see it assumes the files are text files. Can it be done for files with any extension? Also, can it be done for any current folder so there is no reason to modify the bat file? I mean the file to use path where the bat file is located file and executed. Thank you very much anyway even if you don't reply on this comment!

Comment: See my edited code above.  It will work for any filetype that uses text, including HTML files.  Binary files like video and music files aren't supported.